# Web API Bearer token authentication Authorize doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am developing ASP.NET Web API application with Identity 2.0 Bearer authentication. I have configured bearer authentication and implemented SignIn method, so that when I pass header:

```
Authorization: Bearer uGjAWZA1nPc1AqPuKpAzPhb989SYbtGd...
```

It works normally. I can call `User.Identity.GetUserId()` or `User.Identity.GetUserName()`. I even can check if user is in some role or not, and it also works good.

What is doesn't work, is `[Authorize]` attribute. When I specify roles, like that `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` it returns:

```
{
    Message: "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added Role claim when creating your identity?

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
```

Comment: Excellent! What if at one day admin will change role for user? In this case user will no longer be an Admin but he will be able to use admin resources. How to handle this?